# Setting permissions on folders based on the folder name

Tags: permissions, operating-systems, windows-server-2008-r2, window

I'm running Windows Web Server 2008 R2.
I would like to apply specific permissions to any folder named _source automatically, no matter where it appears in the directory structure.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On what level do you want to set those permissions? What would those permissions be?

Comment: Basically I'm looking to give full control (as per security tab) to the directory (and it's sub directories if they exist), to just 2 named users, and remove all other, non-system users, EG leave CREATOR OWNER, SYSTEM and ADMIN.

Comment: Oh wait you didn't mean to let it have any effect on the IIS it's just the edition of the server. Sorry for confusion it. Well on a filesystem level there is no way to do that automatically except by setting the permissions exclusively. This could of course be done by a script.

Comment: That would work. Then I can get task manager to run it every few hours. Interesting.

Comment: Not task manager but task scheduler. You could look into [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/11/22/weekend-scripter-use-powershell-to-get-add-and-remove-ntfs-permissions/) for some ideas to get started.

Comment: Sorry. That's what I meant. My fingers were moving faster than my brain. Thanks for you help. If you would like to post your idea as a response, I can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to do this on a Filesystem level directly, as the access control lists (of NTFS) are limited to single objects. But you could use a script and run it on a schedule using the Windows Task Scheduler and set the permissions using that.

There is a "Hey, Scripting Guy" article titled [Weekend Scripter: Use PowerShell to Get, Add, and Remove NTFS Permissions](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/11/22/weekend-scripter-use-powershell-to-get-add-and-remove-ntfs-permissions/) which could give you some hints on how to achieve the getting/setting of permissions using a PowerShell script.

It's likely that the final result will look something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse *_source | %{
    Get-NTFSAccess $_ | Remove-NTFSAccess
    Add-NTFSAccess -Path $_ -Account 'DOMAIN\User' -AccessRights FullControl
}
```

I didn't really test this, it's just my guess from checking the article.

An another alternative would be to use `icacls` which is a normal commandline utility. The syntax is more complicated but it would work without downloading a third party scripting module. An example article would be this: [Geek of all Trades Setting Permissions from the Command Line](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2009.07.geekofalltrades.aspx)